# Return permutations of all sizes of a string

Tags: java, algorithm

I've been googling for hours and can't figure this out! I am attempting to create a program that will return every size of the permutations of a string that's inputed by the user. I have figured out how to return all permutations that match the length of the original inputed string but I can't figure out how to return sub-sets as well!

For example, if the user enters

"abc"

I want to get the results

a
b
c
ab
ac
bc
cb
abc
... etc

so basically all possible permutations of all possible sizes of the provided string.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong/any corrections to the code to fix this?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Characters extends FindWords {



/**
 * Gets letters provided by user and then
 * runs the character permutation methods
 * within this class.
 */
public void chars (){

    //acquire string provided in Main file
    String c = getLetters();

    //passes the string to the initiate() method
    initiate(c);    


}





/**
 * initiate the permutation easily using only the inputed string as 
 * the parameter.
 * 
 * @param input
 */
void initiate( String input)
{
  //get the length of the given string
  int len = input.length();

  //an array of the characters created by user
  char[ ] in = input.toCharArray( );

  //a malleable string
  StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();

  //array of bools
  boolean[ ] used = new boolean[ len ];


  permAction ( in, out, used, len, 0 );

}









/**
 * Actual action of the permutation
 * 
 * @param in
 * @param out
 * @param used
 * @param len
 * @param x
 */
  void permAction ( char[ ] in, StringBuffer out, 
                    boolean[ ] used, int len, int x){


     //end the recursion for the word if the counter x is the same length as the string
     if( x == len) {
     System.out.println ( out.toString()); 
     return;
     }


     //for every letter in the inputed string
    for( int i = 0; i < len; ++i )
    {       

        //if true
       if( used[i] ) continue;

       //add letter to output string
       out.append( in[i] );      
       used[i] = true; 


       //recursion call
       permAction( in,   out, used, len, x + 1 );       
       used[i] = false;       

       //decrease length by 1
       out.setLength(   out.length() - 1 );   
    }
 }


}
```

Thanks in advance for any help! :)

I found some advice on google about using powersets but I am getting even worse luck with those than I am with this particular implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## For all lengths:

Here is one solution that is based on the idea of the book "Cracking the Coding Interview" (P54):

```
/**
 * List permutation of a string
 * 
 * @param s the input string
 * @return  the list of permutation
 */
public static ArrayList<String> permutation(String s) {
    // The result
    ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
    // If input string's length is 1, return {s}
    if (s.length() == 1) {
        res.add(s);
    } else if (s.length() > 1) {
        int lastIndex = s.length() - 1;
        // Find out the last character
        String last = s.substring(lastIndex);
        // Rest of the string
        String rest = s.substring(0, lastIndex);
        // Perform permutation on the rest string and
        // merge with the last character
        res = merge(permutation(rest), last);
    }
    return res;
}

/**
 * @param list a result of permutation, e.g. {"ab", "ba"}
 * @param c    the last character
 * @return     a merged new list, e.g. {"cab", "acb" ... }
 */
public static ArrayList<String> merge(ArrayList<String> list, String c) {
    ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
    // Loop through all the string in the list
    for (String s : list) {
        // For each string, insert the last character to all possible postions
        // and add them to the new list
        for (int i = 0; i <= s.length(); ++i) {
            String ps = new StringBuffer(s).insert(i, c).toString();
            res.add(ps);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

---

Running output of string "abcd":

- Step 1: Merge [a] and b:
  [ba, ab]
- Step 2: Merge [ba, ab] and c:
  [cba, bca, bac, cab, acb, abc]
- Step 3: Merge [cba, bca, bac, cab, acb, abc] and d:
  [dcba, cdba, cbda, cbad, dbca, bdca, bcda, bcad, dbac, bdac, badc, bacd, dcab, cdab, cadb, cabd, dacb, adcb, acdb, acbd, dabc, adbc, abdc, abcd]

---

## (OR) for fixed size

Use recursion.

- Try each of the letters in turn as the first letter and then find all the permutations of the  remaining letters using a recursive call.
- The base case is when the input is an empty string the only permutation is the empty string.

---

```
public static void permutation(String str) { 
    permutation("", str); 
}
   
private static void permutation(String prefix, String str) {
    int n = str.length();
    if (n == 0) System.out.println(prefix);
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, n));
    }
}
```

(via [Introduction to Programming in Java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Permutations.java.html))

Walkthrough of how to understand what is going on and why this works: (http://learnprogramming.machinesentience.com/java_permutations_recursion)

#### Credits go to  shridutt kothari, SuperJulietta, and Su Yong on SO

Comment: Why the down vote? Have the courtesy to ask for an explanation before down voting!

Comment: This gives not the output that the OP wants. All printed strings have the length 3. But he also wants strings with the length of 2 and 1. I think the term permutations is not correct, but power set.

Comment: not my downvote I'm still trying out your suggestion :)

Comment: Trying this out, this seems to only print the first two two-character permutations (for "abc" it returns "ba, ab") then moves on to 3-character permutations and so on until the highest amt. of characters is reached. Furthermore, in the 3-character set, it always stops at 6 sets even entering for example 6 or 7 characters which would clearly have a larger amount of 3-char possible sets than 6. So this is close but for some reason limited, I will try to look thru the code to fix it but do you see why it might be this way?

Comment: The above is in reference to the top example you give that should essentially provide the powerset of a string